# Download multiple files using loop (and a variable) in R

Tags: r

I need to download a lot of files from an "HTML" link using R.

The links look like:

http://bioinf-applied.charite.de/supernatural_new/src/download_mol.php?sn_id=SN00000001

with the number after `id=` incrementing for each subsequent file. I want to download the first 1000 files, from: `...id=SN00000001` to `...id=SN00001000`

I´m trying to use a loop with a variable to download all those files, but I have no idea how to construct this code in R.

Comment: You could probably use a combination of `paste()`, `mapply()` and `download.file()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for(i in 1:1000){
  x <- sprintf("%08d", i)
  myPath <- paste0("http://bioinf-applied.charite.de/supernatural_new/src/download_mol.php?sn_id=SN", x)
  download.file(myPath, paste0("SN", x, ".mol"))
}
```