# downloading multiple nc4 files from nasa

Tags: r

I'm trying to download multiple .nc4 format files from nasa [here](https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/GLDAS_NOAH025_3H_2.1/summary)

There are 29217 links I'm trying to download from January 1 2010 to December 31 2019. However, I'm finding it difficult in trying to construct the syntax for it.

Although, the site gives you the option of downloading a list of the html links to the files, if there's a quick method of downloading all of these, it will be much appreciated.

I've tried looking here:
[Download multiple files using loop (and a variable) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347437/download-multiple-files-using-loop-and-a-variable-in-r)

However, the files do not follow a simple format like the one above.

The format is this:
`GLDAS_NOAH025_3H.A20100101.0000.021.ncf`
where `2010` represents the year, and `0101`  where the last digit represents the day, and `0000` are the hours, which are 3hour incremental.

So essential, a syntax that can workout the 3hr incremental, days and year.

`0000` starts at this at the first 3 hours, then increases to `2100` and resets. This should make 8 files per day, and in a year that is ~2920 files.

Comment: Don't use R for this. NASA provides information on how to download via FTP: https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/information/howto?title=How%20to%20Download%20Data%20Files%20from%20HTTPS%20Service%20with%20wget

Comment: @Ventrilocus I find using wget long and confusing, so I opted for R. Although, I managed to do it by downloading the list of html links, then using the `downloadThemAll!` extension from firefox. However, having a code for this would help in the future if things are not always this smooth.